# encrypt in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgcrypto

i have a problem with this:

```
 insert into usuario (usuario, clave) values ('alex', encrypt('11112222', 'password','3des'))
```

The Result:

```
ERROR: no exists the functión encrypt(unknown, unknown, unknown)
SQL state: 42883
```

the extension pgcrypto is already install.

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. Might be that you're not connected to the db pgcrypto is installed in, or that the `search_path` can't reach its functions. Try `\dx pgcrypto` in psql and `show search_path;`

Comment: I resolved the problem: In this case, left the name table in the moment to call the function. Example - Problem: `encrypt('11112222', 'password','3des')` - Solution: `**name_table**.encrypt('11112222', 'password','3des')`